# How to display value prop of react Ace Editor onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

I'm looking to display the value prop from the React Ace Editor. Just looking to console.log it for now.

I'm not sure how to access it and display it when the "see code" button is clicked.

Here is the code I'm currently working on at the moment:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";

import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";

function onChange(newValue) {
  console.log("change", newValue);
}

class Code extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { code: `console.log("Hello World")` };
  }

  runCode = () => {
    console.log(this.props.aceEditor.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <AceEditor
          mode="javascript"
          theme="github"
          fontSize={16}
          value={this.state.code}
          onChange={onChange}
          name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
          editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
        />
        <div>
          <h2>Controls:</h2>
          <button onClick={this.runCode}>see code</button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Code;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { code: `console.log("Hello World")` };
 this.runCode = this.runCode.bind(this);
}
```

You need to bind the runCode function to your class. You can do this in your constructor as shown above.